# How can I calculate the percentage of time on average per episode in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
Episode
-----------------------------------
| Id | Name | Duration | SeasonId |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | ..   | 00:54:34 | 1        |
| 2  | ..   | 00:49:56 | 1        |
-----------------------------------

Profile
----------------------
| Id | Name | UserId |
----------------------
| 1  | ..   | 1      |
| 2  | ..   | 1      | 
----------------------

WatchHistory
------------------------------------
| ProfileId | EpisodeId | Progress |
------------------------------------
| 1         | 1         | 00:17:17 |
| 2         | 1         | 00:54:34 |
| 1         | 2         | 00:49:56 |
------------------------------------
```

I want to calculate the average percentage profiles watched each episode, but I cant seem to figure out how to do this.

For episode 1, profile 1 watched around 31,7 percent, profile 2 watched 100 percent, so episode 1 has been watched on average around 65,8 percent.

The result should look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EpisodeId | EpisodeName | EpisodeDuration | PercentageWatchedAverage |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | ..          | 00:54:34        | 66                       |
| 2         | ..          | 00:49:56        | 100                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I accomplish this result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I have tried using the WITH clause, but this didnt lead to anything. Ive scrapped all my previous attempts. I use Sql Server Management Studio. I can generate everything you see in the question except for the percentage column

Comment: According to your logic, if someone watches None of an episode, they're not counted in the calculation.  But if they watch 1 second of an episode, they are.  Are you sure that's the logic that you need?

Comment: What datatype are your Duration and Progress columns?  Do you need to account for people skipping parts of an episode, using fast-forward or skip, re-watching the same part of an episode more than once, watch the whole episode, except for the end-credits, etc?  *(Or are you assuming all of that is accounted for in the WatchHistory table?)*

Comment: Whenever people havent watched it they dont have to be included in the equation. The values in the database have all been in the application, so there isnt any need to take skipping parts into account. The only thing I need to know is how to calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starter...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12f0a734716d16e666318ec54a705fbd

```
SELECT
  Episode.id,
  AvgProgress.seconds * 100.0
  /
  DATEDIFF(second, 0, Episode.duration)
FROM
  Episode
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    EpisodeID,
    AVG(
      DATEDIFF(second, 0, Progress)
    )
      AS seconds
  FROM
    WatchHistory
  GROUP BY
    EpisodeID
)
  AS AvgProgress
    ON AvgProgress.EpisodeID = Episode.id
```